# Calling web service with ssl certificates

Tags: java, rest, web-services, curl, ssl-certificate

How do I call the same web service with ssl certificate mentioned below in Java?

curl -v --cert kkk.cer --key kkk.private --pass kkk --cacert sslservercachain.cer -H "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded" https://hello-signs.api-dev.myname.com/v2/oauth2/client_credential/accesstoken?grant_type=client_credentials -d "client_id=xxccvvbbnniioopp&client_secret=zoopopopopopppp"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Meta: I believe this is as least partly dupe -- I've seen (quite a few) variations on it, but can't find any now. May add later if I do (or anyone else feel free to).

There are probably thousands of possible answers to this, as it seems nearly everyone with a computer has written their own HTTP-client (including HTTPS) library, plus there are actually several implementations of SSL/TLS usable from Java in various situations. For simplicity I will show the only ones **built-in to standard Sun/Oracle/OpenJDK Java**: the `HttpsURLConnection` class which builds on the `JSSE` SSL/TLS implementation. (Other implementations of Java like Android, IBM, and maybe Apple may differ here, but at least Android probably wouldn't be using curl.)

Also it depends on what the files you currently have are, which in turn varies depending on the build of curl you are using -- curl supports about a dozen SSL/TLS stacks, which use a variety of file formats. Since you don't give this information, I'm going to guess your curl uses openssl (or one of its forks) which in turn uses PEM-format files for `--cert --key --cacert`. If not, edit your question to include this information (and to be safe ping me; I'm not sure if I get notified for Q edits).

Subject to those caveats:

To use SSL/TLS certificates and keys in JSSE (and HttpsURLConnection) you need them to be either in Java-format files or in suitable Java objects in memory. The former is usually easier, so I'll show that. Start by using OpenSSL to **convert the client key PLUS cert(s) to PKCS12**:

```
openssl pkcs12 -export -in kkk.cer -inkey kkk.private -out kkk.pkcs12 
# use a different filename if you prefer
# enter passwords as needed; do _not_ use an empty password for the pkcs12
# (if so OpenSSL will create a file Java cannot decrypt, defeating your goal)
```

For Java 9 up this is enough; they use PKCS12 format for keystores by default. Older versions used JKS format by default, although more recent updates of Java 8 have a kludge: even when you specify or default that the format is JKS it can actually read PKCS12 format as well -- see item `keystore.compat` in file `JRE/lib/security/java.security`. Even before that Java allowed you to *specify* PKCS12 format when using it, but if you find it more convenient not to, you can convert PKCS12 format to JKS format with:

```
keytool -importkeystore -srckeystore kkk.pkcs12 -srcstoretype pkcs12 -destkeystore kkk.jks 
# use the same password for output (jks) as input (p12) otherwise 
# you may create a privatekey entry that cannot be used later
```

You **also want the cert(s) used to validate the server** in a keystore file; this usually is a separate file and usually called a 'truststore' instead of 'keystore' for clarity. In this case you need to use `keytool` and you can only do one cert at a time; if `sslservercachain` contains multiple certs as its name suggests, you must split them into separate files (on most Linuxes and some other Unixes `csplit` can do this easily, otherwise any text editting tool should manage), then do for each

```
keytool -import -keystore trust.<see below> -alias <unique> -file <filename> 
# use a unique alias for each cert: if you know what they are, 
# names like intermediate, root, bridge, etc may be helpful;
# otherwise just use arbitrary names like a b c or 1 2 3 .
```

As above for Java 9+ this will create pkcs12 and you should name it accordingly. In Java 8 it will default to JKS but you can specify `-storetype pkcs12` (and again name it accordingly). Below Java 8 you must use JKS (the provider in those versions *did* support pkcs12 for privatekey entries but not for trustedcert entries).

With those files prepared and set as system properties, **use `URL` to create an `HttpsURLConnection`** with the desired header, body and method (`curl -d` automatically sets `POST` -- incidentally it also sets form-urlencoded so you didn't actually need to do that explicitly in curl, but you do need to in Java). See the javadoc for the base class [URLConnection](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/net/URLConnection.html) and its linked subclasses (HttpURLConnection and HttpsURLConnection); if you have a Java IDE (like Eclipse or Intellij) these javadocs should appear automatically when you start entering code.

```
// once at he beginning of your program (before any use of default SSLContext)
// or instead can be done on the command line with -Dprop=value 
System.setProperty ("javax.net.ssl.keyStore", filepath);
System.setProperty ("javax.net.ssl.keyStorePassword", password);
System.setProperty ("javax.net.ssl.keyStoreType", "PKCS12" or "JKS"); -- if not default
System.setProperty ("javax.net.ssl.trustStore", filepath);
System.setProperty ("javax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword", password);
System.setProperty ("javax.net.ssl.trustStoreType", "PKCS12" or "JKS"); -- if not default

// when (each time) you want to make a request:
URL url = new URL ("https://hello-signs.api-dev.myname.com/v2/oauth2/client_credential/accesstoken?grant_type=client_credentials");
HttpsURLConnection conn = (HttpsURLConnection) url.openConnection();
// we aren't actually using S-specific items, so could instead use 
// HttpURLConnection especially if you want to mix HTTPS and HTTP;
// or you could use the Https version to tweak some SSL/TLS parameters
conn.setRequestMethod ("POST");
conn.setRequestHeader ("Content-Type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
conn.setDoOutput (true);
OutputStream os = conn.getOutputStream(); 
os.write ("client_id=xxccvvbbnniioopp&client_secret=zoopopopopopppp".getBytes());
os.close();
os.connect(); // optional, can help localize exceptions

// depending on what you want to do with the result(s):
... conn.getResponseCode() and/or conn.getResponseMessage() ...
... conn.getHeaderField{,Int,Long,s}("id") ...
... conn.getContent{Type,Length[Long],Encoding,}() ... 
... conn.getInputStream() then read from it, including decoding various formats or charsets as needed/desired ...
conn.disconnect(); // when done
```